# How to test @Model data classes from Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, testing, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to test a mapper function between my UI layer and my Domain layer.

But I get an exception thrown of `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not in a frame`

This exception goes away if I change my UIModel to have a `val` instead of a `var` but then it is useless with the model updates that Jetpack Compose offers.

Is there a way to test this type of mapper?

```
import androidx.compose.Model
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
import org.junit.Test

class DataModelMapperTest {

    @Test
    fun `data model to ui model`() {
        val model = DataModel(5)
        val uiModel = UIModel(5)

        assertEquals(uiModel, model.toUIModel())
    }

    @Test
    fun `ui model to data model`() {
        val model = DataModel(5)
        val uiModel = UIModel(5)

        assertEquals(model, uiModel.toDataModel())
    }

}

@Model
data class UIModel(var value: Int)

data class DataModel(val value: Int)

fun DataModel.toUIModel(): UIModel = UIModel(this.value)

fun UIModel.toDataModel(): DataModel = DataModel(this.value)
```

Comment: It would appear that the annotation processor for `@Model` is still getting invoked and is generating something that doesn't play well with unit tests. If you switch to instrumented tests, I believe that there are recipes for writing Compose tests that you might be able to leverage. Probably eventually there will be unit test solutions too, but I think we're a *long* way off from getting a stable Compose release, so there will be these sorts of limitations for a while.

Comment: Small nit: it's not an annotation processor, it's a compiler plugin.  Compose does not use any annotation processors.

Answer (score 1):

I was hitting the same issue. Here is what I figured out: I have to initialize my model objects that is annotated with `@Model` within (or maybe after) call to `setContent()`.

Google's [JetNews](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/dev08/JetNews) sample comes with [`ComposeTestRule.launchJetNewsApp()`](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/dev08/JetNews/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/jetnews/TestHelper.kt#L33) function which is called by `JetnewsUiTest.setUp()`. Their test class comes with full use of androidx.ui:ui-test stuff including `createComposeRule()`. You might want to have a look at it.